# How can I use the latest AppleJavaExtensions with maven?

Tags: java, macos, maven

I've developed a Java application that uses some of the [Apple Java Extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/index.html) to provide a better experience for Mac users. To compile the application on Windows I've previously just used Eclipse, setting the AppleJavaExtensions.jar as a Referenced Library.

Now I'm looking to build using maven I'm having an issue. I've added the following to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.apple</groupId>
  <artifactId>AppleJavaExtensions</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

However the AppleJavaExtensions.jar downloaded is out of date - it doesn't have AboutHandler or OpenFilesHandler etc.

Is there a maven repository that offers a more up to date version?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it myself, but the **OrangeExtensions** project does have `AboutHandler` and `OpenFilesHandler`: http://ymasory.github.com/OrangeExtensions/

It's in Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.yuvimasory</groupId>
  <artifactId>orange-extensions</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```